# Access cacheSweave objects from cache

Tags: r, sweave

I use [Sweave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweave) and [cacheSweave](http://www.biometrics.mtu.edu/CRAN/web/packages/cacheSweave/) with pleasure.

Occasionally I have a document in which some section takes a really long time (like 20 minutes or something) and after processing I'd like to open up the objects it created and play around with them in an interactive session.

Does anyone know a method for doing that, presumably by fetching directly against the `stashR` database or something?

Comment: This isn't really an answer, but if your Sweave file takes 20 minutes to run, mightn't you be better off doing the lengthy calculations in a separate R script and `save()`-ing them, then doing `load()` from Sweave and just displaying the results?

Comment: Sometimes that would work well, but sometimes I want to show the calculation in the document and I'd like to avoid writing it in two different places.

Answer (score 2):

I would have preferred to put this as a comment, but i dont have an account here, so anyway.
The easiest way to do this is probably to put save.image() statements at strategic points in the .Rnw file, so that all objects created at that point are saved. Then, one can open up a new instance of R and interact with the objects without altering the sweave file. HTH.

Comment: Thanks, that'll work.  I'd still like something that would let me directly inspect the cache files, but this gets me most of the way to a workable workflow.